# filter and redirect specific messages in BusyBox yocto project

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, syslog, busybox

There are specific error messages, which keep displaying on the console each 7 seconds.
i need to stop those messages at least from displaying as it is really annoying and filter via BusyBox in Yocto project.

I get those error messages:

Board_Name user.err kernel: [ 2110.791587] imx6-mipi-csi2: clock lane timeout, phy_state = 0x000002f0
Board_Name user.err kernel: [ 2110.801033] imx-ipuv3-csi imx-ipuv3-csi.0: pipeline start failed with -110

those keep floating in the terminal, and need to store it in log file and stop floating on consol.

Thanks

I tried to write the following code/rules in syslog.conf:

```
if $msg contains 'imx6-mipi-csi2' then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/data_rw/kernel_errors.log")
}
```

but it did have any reflect on the error messages.

Comment: Is there a reason for not fixing/disabling CSI?